# How do I view the file paths that were last modified in git?

Tags: git

What git command will display a list of all committed modifications, one modified file per line, with the file's path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

```
git log --stat
```

is what you're after.

Comment: Looks great, thanks. Can you make it show the full untrimmed path?

Comment: I wasn't aware that it did trim paths. Oh, do you mean the absolute path?

Comment: Or is it because you're not at the top level of the working tree?

Comment: it just trims them. The documentation reveals this parameter to set the width to 200: git log --stat=200,200.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get a full list without trimming:

```
git log --stat=200 --stat-name-width=150
```

`200` stands for a total width of the output, and `150` for the width of a file name column. If name-width is bigger than total width it will be truncated.